# ES6 how to export all item from one file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to export all methods of a file from another file.

currently I am doing this, and it works. How can I merge below two into 1 export expression

```
import  * as db  from './web/query';
export default db;
```

I tried below written 1 line exports but all failed

```
export *   from './web/query';  //==error
export *  as default  from './web/query';  //==error
export *  as {default}  from './web/query';  //==error
export from from './web/query'; //== error
export default from './web/query'; //== error
```

**Error means**

```
import db from '../db/index';
```

db is undefined here. However the the first methods works

**Inside of file './web/query' looks like**

```
export function foo(){}
export function baar(){}
```

Comment: What error do you get for `export *   from './web/query';`?

Comment: undefined in import

Comment: Uhm, provide more details. Apparently you get it from the code you did not provide here.

Comment: And what is exported from `./web/query`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot in ES2016. To create a module namespace object, you need to give it an identifier (like `db`) in your current module scope, and then re-export that. There's no way around it.

There is however a stage 1 [proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-ns-from) to add the `export * as default from …` syntax you were trying.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I merge below two into 1 export expression

You cannot.

ES2015 (and ES2016) does not provide a syntax that would allow you to import all the named exports from a file and export the object (with those as its properties) as default in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the named exports of another file with `export * from '<FILE>';`.

```js
// a.js
export const one = '1';
export const two = '2';
```

```js
// b.js
export * from './a.js';
```

```js
// c.js
import { one, two } from './b.js';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

a.js:

```
const fakeName = "Blabla";
const fakeAge = 33;

module.exports = {fakeName, fakeAge}
```

b.js:

```
 const name = "Someone";
 let age = 22;

module.exports = { name, age}
```

c.mjs:

```
export  * from './a.js';
export * from './b.js';
```

index.mjs:

```
import * as  AllClass from './c.mjs'
export default AllClass
```

use it in e.g server.mjs:

```
import AllClass from './index.mjs'

console.log("fakeName:", AllClass.fakeName);
console.log("NAME:",AllClass.name);
```

It's just hard not to get confused with ESModule imports/exports and CommonJS imports and exports...