# How to setup an index file in ES6 using export * from '...'

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules

I am trying to set up a simple index file for all of my models. Ultimately, my goal would be to do something like this...

```
// models/A.model.js
...
const A = model(...);
const otherA = ...;
export { A, otherA };

// models/B.model.js
...
const B = model(...);
const otherB = ...
export { B, otherB };

// models/index.js
export * from './A.model.js';
export * from './B.model.js';

// server/index.js
import * as models from './models'
models.A
models.otherA
```

etc.

Currently it appears as if the models/index.js file is not exporting anything. I may be doing this completely wrong. I am using Babel and have used [this](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-modules) as a reference

Comment: @Phil I don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: This should work. What makes it appear as if index.js is not exporting anything? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi oops, I closed with the wrong duplicate. Was meant to be [import modules from files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory). Can re-open if it appears OP has a different problem

Comment: @Phil If I re-opened I'd have to vote to close as not reproducable or missing information :-) Let's wait for clarification from the OP

Comment: @Bergi There are no errors, but with the code as written gives an empty object as models in server/index.js, where I would expect to be able to access models.A and models.otherA, etc.

Comment: How are you running the code, are you using a transpiler? What's the exact code you are using, can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: @Phil I have seen those other questions, but it appears as if [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236920/es6-how-to-export-all-item-from-one-file) they are trying to export all the named exports from one file as a default for another. They never really explain anything after that. From the first [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/import-modules-from-files-in-directory) they are importing the named exports of one file through an index. This also doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Bergi This is part of a simple express app. I am using webpack to bundle and using 'babel-loader' to transpile the code. I apologize for the brevity. I am not an expert by any means. The problem appears to be that models/index.js is not exporting anything.

Comment: Can you post the transpiled code?

Comment: @Bergi From looking at the transpiled code the problem actually comes from the transform-runtime plugin injecting import statements when using 'export * from' see [#2877](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2877). Thank you for your help.