# How to setup Babel to use ES2015 `export * as X from Y` syntax?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I just want to use this syntax:

```
export * as Utils from './utils';
```

But Babel says it can't parse this line:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Seems like `transform-export-extensions` should do what I want, but it don't.

---

I use latest babel 7 & webpack 4

My `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-export-extensions",
    ]
}
```

In webpack config I have:

```
...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087421/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js-typeerror - check this maybe

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236920/es6-how-to-export-all-item-from-one-file. The proposal has been accepted, you might need to update your tooling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with just

```
import * as Utils from './utils';
export {Utils};
```